# what does "as the next big thing" mean in the sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Many college superstar athlete are hailed as the next big thing, but then flop at the professional level.

I could not understand the meaning of "as the next big thing". What does it mean?

Comment: To imbibe means to drink.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Thanks for your commet, but imbibe also means "absorb or assimilate (ideas or knowledge).
"if one does not imbibe the culture one cannot succeed""

Answer (score 1):

Hail, verb (2), def. 1a [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hail).

> to greet with enthusiastic approval : acclaim
>       - ***hailed* as** a great success

If someone is hailed as the next big thing, you may consider them a [rising star](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rising%20star), an embodiment of the future of the field (in this case, athletics or sports), or more generally, just expected to be uniquely successful in a given field.